# PHP My Select isn't working?

Tags: php, mysql

I believe my PHP to be functioning perfectly, therefore I think it's a query error. When I proceed, with form details stored in the session... it happily returns my Posted information but doesn't seem to be pulling anything from my database - there is a row in my database containing the email address I am using.  Does anybody see anything blatantly wrong with this PHP?

Thanks for your help.

```
<?php
session_start();
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "privatedbroot";
$password = "not4ulol";
$dbname = "pdb_inventory";
$status = $_GET["action"];
$_SESSION["Cemail"] = $_POST["CEMAIL"];
$_SESSION["Access"] = md5($_POST["ACCESS"]);
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);


    $sql = "SELECT CEMAIL, ACCESS FROM POPU WHERE `CEMAIL`= ".$_SESSION['Cemail'];
    echo $sql;
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            if ($_SESSION["Access"] == $row["ACCESS"]){
                echo "password correct!";
            } else {
                echo "password wrong!";
            }
        }
    }else{
        echo "ur email is wrong m8.";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Use `'` around your session variable in the query string.

Comment: Your code contains many syntax errors. 
Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code.

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: @MarcB reserved word, which one?

Comment: poop. it's actually "accessible" for the reserved word. doh... and... interesting... I flagged for re-open and it immediately did. guess that's another perk for the auto-close stuff.

Comment: @MarcB *You're forgiven* ;-) The reopen can be done by any gold member, no need to flag it if you're gold. Just hit "reopen" ;-) yeah... cool feature on the flag.

Comment: @MarcB we can delete our comments now, unless you still want 'em ;-)

Comment: I'll just let my mistake hang out there. time to wear a hairshirt for a while.

Comment: @MarcB I had to go look and see where you may have thought `ACCESS` was a reserved word. Like Jay (answer below if not deleted yet) and [as per my comment to him](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32143912/php-my-select-isnt-working#comment52177975_32143967) have experience with Oracle. Yeah.. it is in Oracle http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b40103/app_oracle_reserved_words.htm - I think that mystery's been solved ;-)

Comment: Please do not do your login like that, I get headache from that.. use those functions: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$cemail = $_SESSION['Cemail'];
$sql = "SELECT CEMAIL, ACCESS FROM POPU WHERE `CEMAIL`= '$cemail'";
```